# Error in Kerne.php line 703 symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, caching, permissions, symfony4

In Kernel.php line 703:

Warning: unlink(/home/someuser/theproject/var/cache/de_/ContainerNipRDo8.legacy): No such file or directory

Comment: I opened a github issue under symfony project if you are still interested https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26158#issuecomment-365163458

Answer (score 0):

Remove cache file into `var/cache`.

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Comment: That did not work, there is a discution about it git, people are working on it and it seems related with the debug options, it seems like in stackoverflow that only thing that happend was a downvote for me. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/26158#issuecomment-365163458